# Swap on Pancake swap V3 using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, pancakeswap

How can I programatically swap this transaction (https://bscscan.com/tx/0xeb82366f808d194bcae4ede724bb0dbaeebc431fe492ff70b1c3c7a5d5762d47) using web3.py?

When swapped from their official webgui they used `multicall` to wrap `exactInputSingle`. I tried `exactInputSingle` directly but got `Fail with error 'STF'` (https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0dbb4f4ba7710521b1ef742b36266c135a2e182e9199246c2fe4c05d80ba9392 )

Here's the source code of what I did so far

```py
import os
import time
from web3 import Web3, Account
import json
import dotenv

dotenv.load_dotenv()
account = Account.from_key(os.environ.get("PKEY"))
account.address

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org"))
contract = w3.eth.contract(
    address=w3.to_checksum_address("0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4"),
    abi=json.load(open("playground/abi.json")),
)

tx_params = (
    w3.to_checksum_address("0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955"),
    w3.to_checksum_address("0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56"),
    500,
    w3.to_checksum_address("0x82A7C4C451EE04B93BB36DE492B171909003FC13"),
    10000000000000000,
    9049834293527845,
    0,
)
build_tx_params = {
    "deadline": int(time.time()) + 60 * 20,
    "from": w3.to_checksum_address("0x82A7C4C451EE04B93BB36DE492B171909003FC13"),
    "gas": 173767,
    "maxPriorityFeePerGas": w3.eth.max_priority_fee,
    "maxFeePerGas": 3 * 10**9,
    "nonce": w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
}
tx = contract.functions.exactInputSingle(tx_params).build_transaction(build_tx_params)

raw_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, account.key).rawTransaction
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(raw_transaction)
```